# ERROR 2006 (HY000) line 9675: MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql

I am trying to restore a database (size 477mb) and keep getting the error: *MySQL server has gone away*. I am not sure how to fix this error. I have tried:

- Changing the `max_allowed_packets` to 600M.
- Increasing the `wait_timeout` to 2880000.

But none of these helped. This is the exact error message:

> 18:13:52 Restoring C:\Users\Niting\Documents\Backup 20120918 0000.sql
>
> Running: mysql.exe --defaults-extra-file="c:\users\niting\appdata\local\temp\tmp_krvy8.cnf"
>   --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments < "C:\Users\Niting\Documents\Backup 20120918 0000.sql"`
>
> ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 9675: MySQL server has gone away

Line 9675 Contains

```
(
3434,'','','brocar',18730,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'false',NULL,NULL,'true',NULL,'Once',NULL,NULL,NULL
,NULL,NULL,'false',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'false'
,NULL,'false','false',NULL,'Accomplishment','false',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
,NULL,NULL,NULL,71,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
,NULL,'2011-10-30','true',0,'false',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'false'
,NULL,NULL,'2011-10-30',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2011-10-30','14:35:27'
),
```

That line is under this insert:

```
INSERT INTO `tbldelinspect` (
`DELINSPECTID`,`DATE`,`TIME`,`USER`,`PIECEID`,`MARQUE`,`MODEL`,`SN`,`FROMTTAF`
,`FROMDATE`,`TBOHRS`,`INSTALLTTAF`,`INSTALLDATE`,`INSTALLCUSTOM`,`TBOMONTH`
,`HRSWARNING`,`MONTHWARNING`,`NOM`,`ISDUE`,`ACREG`,`DESCRIPTION`,`ISAD`
,`ADWHATSDONE`,`ADTYPE`,`NBSTART`,`CUSTOMCOMPUTEID`,`GROUPID`,`INVENTAIREID`
,`ATACODE`,`ADDONE`,`ADINTERVALTYPE`,`REMAINHRS`,`DUETTAF`,`DATENEXTINSPECT`
,`NOTE`,`CORRECTION`,`SHORTDESC`,`TTSO`,`REMAINMONTH`,`WARN`,`TSO`,`ISINSPECTION`
,`ISCURRENTINSPECTION`,`MONTHSATINSTALL`,`ACTION`,`UPDATE_`,`TSN`,`TTSN`,`MSN`
,`TMSN`,`REMAINCUSTOM`,`DUECUSTOM`,`TMSO`,`AIRCRAFTID`,`CUSTOMTBO`,`FROMCUSTOM`
,`CUSTOMWARNING`,`CUSTSN`,`TCUSTSN`,`CUSTOMATINSTALL`,`TCUSTSO`,`CUSTOMENGINE`
,`OLDMAXNG`,`MAXNG`,`ADCOMPONENT`,`LASTUPDATE`,`KEEPHISTORY`,`STARTADD`,`ISTASK`
,`TASKNO`,`RELATEDPIECEID`,`AIRCRAFTZONE`,`REFERENCE`,`PARTNO`,`TEMPLATEKEY`
,`ISSPECIALINSPECT`,`MANUALNEXTDUETTAF`,`MANUALNEXTDUECUSTOM`,`MANUALNEXTDUEDATE`
,`PERFAFTERXTTAF`,`PERFAFTERXMONTH`,`PERFAFTERXCYCLE`,`SPECIALTASKLINKPIECEID`
,`TOLERANCEVALUE`,`ASSEMBLYMASTERID`,`DELDATE`,`DELTIME`
) 
VALUES
```

Any ideas how to get over this issue so I can restore my MySQL database?

Comment: Can we get a resolution? How did you "figure" this issue out?

Answer (score 1):

The problem does not appear to be due to `max_allowed_packet`, as that generates a very specific message, which should be `Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes`. Are you sure that the MySQL server is not crashing due to your statement? Can you check `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Uptime'` to make sure that the server is up for as long as you expect it should be?

If it's crashing/restarting during your `INSERT` for loading a dump, that would be likely due either to running out of disk space or existing corruption.

Comment: I am very new to MySQL. This backup was given to me by somebody else. I googled and checked the "Show Status Uptime" and it gave me a value of 150642.  My hard disk seems to have about 2gb of free space and the size of the .sql file is 477mb.